# Ошибка NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть код который реализует key-values хранилище.

---

```
import argparse
import json
import tempfile
import os


STORAGE_PATH = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), 'storage.data')


def get_data():
    if not os.path.exists(STORAGE_PATH):
        return {}
    with open(STORAGE_PATH, 'r') as f:
        raw_data = f.read()
        if raw_data:
            return json.loads(raw_data)
        return {}


def put(key, value):
    data = get_data()

    if key in data:
        data[key].append(value)
    else:
        data[key] = [value]

    with open(STORAGE_PATH, 'w') as f:
        f.write(json.dumps(data))


def get(key):
    data = get_data()
    return data.get(key)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--key', help='Key', action='store', dest='key', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--val', help='Value', action='store', dest='val')

    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.key and args.val:
        put(args.key, args.val)
    elif args.key:
        for i in get(args.key):
            print(i, end=" ")
```

После добавления цикла, при проверке на неправильный ключ выдает ошибку

```
elif args.key:
        for i in get(args.key):
            print(i, end=" ")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

Проблема в том, что вы не создаете сам файл - только лишь путь до него

```
STORAGE_PATH = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), 'storage.data')
```

В данном случае проверка `not os.path.exists(STORAGE_PATH)` всегда возвращает `True`, следовательно функция `get_data` всегда возвращает пустой словарь. Далее метод `data.get(key)` из функции `get` возвращает None, который нельзя проитерировать.

Попробуйте использовать к примеру [tempfile.TemporaryFile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryFile)

Answer (score 0):

Метод get() у словарей возвращает None если такого ключа нет. Рекомендую в цикле сначала проверять, что возвращает функция get_data(). И стоит добавить логирование в те моменты, где проверяется наличие файла, и наличие в нем содержимого, чтобы понять причину пустого словаря